# which algorithm you recommended for human body detection by camera? in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ar.drone

use for drone quadcopter to track human body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem depend on many factors :

1. Computational **resources**.
2. **Quality** of images.
3. How much **accuracy** do you expect from the algorithm

By the way, the easiest way for implementing such algorithm is **[Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html)** which is implemented in OpenCV. You can train your own model or you can use the trained model which exists in openCV files. This method support three feature types: HOG,LBP and HAAR. The base of this method is paper [Viola and Jones](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/viola/Pubs/Detect/violaJones_CVPR2001.pdf) published on 2001. The test time is near to online in an ordinary computer.

If you need more accurate method you can try **DPM** (deformable part models) based method. There are many released version of this method on the internet. The speed of detection is almost 2 HZ.

If you need more accuracy I suggest you to go forward with CNN (**Convolutional Neural Networks**). Of Course you need more computational resources (GPU or high spec CPUs)

Comment: thanks for the help!